# "KeyError: 'added' "when importing different lists of json

Tags: python, json, django

I'm getting a "KeyError: 'added'" Error when i try to import one of my three lists inside a json file. The list i'm trying to import is the one called "added". I had this working when it was just one list without the name "added" on top but now it seems like i can't access the list anymore. I want to individually import them basically.

### This is my code to get the Json parts before i import them into the database:

```
import requests
import json

from users.models import Facility, FacilityAddress, FacilityInspectionInfo, FacilityComplaints
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

IMPORT_URL = 'https://url/imports.json'

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def import_facility_from_file(self, data):
                    UUID = data.get('UUID', None)
                    Name = data.get('Name', None)
                    PrimaryAddress = data["AddressInfo"]["PrimaryAddress"]

""" This is what happens after the database entry related code """

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """
        Call the function to import data from json url
        """
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.get(
            url=IMPORT_URL,
            headers=headers,
        )

        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()

        for key, data_object in data.items():
            self.import_facility_from_file(data_object)
```

### The new version of the Json File that im trying to use but thats causing the error:

```
{
"added":
{"125hk24h5kjh43k5":
{
"UUID":"125hk24h5kjh43k5",
"Name":"Test Facility 1",
"AddressInfo":
{"PrimaryAddress":"1234 Drive RD"},
"ImporterLastModifiedTimestamp":1643721420}},

"deleted":["235hk24h5kjh43k5,235hk345789h43k5"],

"modified":{"995hk24h5kjh43k5":
{
"UUID":"995hk24h5kjh43k5",
"Name":"Test Facility 2",
"AddressInfo":
{"PrimaryAddress":"2345 Test RD"},
"ImporterLastModifiedTimestamp":1643721420}
}
}
```

The old version of the json file that worked perfectly with the code i intially wrote:

```
{"00016ed7be4872a19d6e16afc98a7389b2bb324a2":
{"UUID":"00016ed7be4872a19d6e1ed6f36b647f3eb41cadedd2130b103a5851caebc26fbbbf24c2f1a64d2cf34ac4e03aaa30309816f58c397e6afc98a7389b2bb324a2","Name":"Test Facility","IssuedNumber":"123456","Licensee":"Test Licensee","Email":"test@example.com","AdministratorName":"Test Name","TelephoneNumber":"(123) 456-7890324879","ImporterLastModifiedTimestamp":"1362985200",
    "AddressInfo":{"PrimaryAddress":"123 Fake Road","SecondaryAddress":"","City":"Testcity","RegionOrState":"TX","PostalCode":"12345","Geolocation":"00.0000,-00.0000"},"Capacity":100,"MostRecentLicenseTimestamp":1575180000,"ClosedTimestamp":0,
    "InspectionInfo":{"ComplaintRelatedVisits":0,"InspectionRelatedVisits":0,"NumberOfVisits":0,"LastVisitTimestamp":0},
    "Complaints":{"ComplaintsTypeA":0,"ComplaintsTypeB":0,"SubstantiatedAllegations":0,"TotalAllegations":0}},
    
"00016ed7be4872a15435435435b2bb324a2":
{"UUID":"000c93dcb7a0b3d5783bb330892aff6abdb9fb57a7d3701c2d903f3640877579f3173ecd8a80532f6c3d53dbacde78a6a54ae42fef321a5793f5a01934f8de7a","Name":"Test Facility 2","IssuedNumber":"123456","Licensee":"Test Licensee","Email":"test@example.com","AdministratorName":"Test Name","TelephoneNumber":"(123) 456-7890324879","ImporterLastModifiedTimestamp":"1362985200",
    "AddressInfo":{"PrimaryAddress":"123 Fake Road","SecondaryAddress":"","City":"Testcity","RegionOrState":"TX","PostalCode":"12345","Geolocation":"00.0000,-00.0000"},"Capacity":100,"MostRecentLicenseTimestamp":1575180000,"ClosedTimestamp":0,
    "InspectionInfo":{"ComplaintRelatedVisits":0,"InspectionRelatedVisits":0,"NumberOfVisits":0,"LastVisitTimestamp":0},
    "Complaints":{"ComplaintsTypeA":0,"ComplaintsTypeB":0,"SubstantiatedAllegations":0,"TotalAllegations":0}},

"00234324324343243afc98a7389b2bb324a2":
{"UUID":"fffd4dec10054e6e1deb2a2266a7c6bb0136ba46222e734ceed5855651f735cfbe0bb66cfaf27c3d175ae261a8f6df0c36b5390d15c70b07d67e35e1081aaf6d","Name":"Test Facility 3","IssuedNumber":"123456","Licensee":"Test Licensee","Email":"test@example.com","AdministratorName":"Test Name","TelephoneNumber":"(123) 456-7890324879","ImporterLastModifiedTimestamp":"1362985200",
    "AddressInfo":{"PrimaryAddress":"123 Fake Road","SecondaryAddress":"","City":"Testcity","RegionOrState":"TX","PostalCode":"12345","Geolocation":"00.0000,-00.0000"},"Capacity":100,"MostRecentLicenseTimestamp":1575180000,"ClosedTimestamp":0,
    "InspectionInfo":{"ComplaintRelatedVisits":0,"InspectionRelatedVisits":0,"NumberOfVisits":0,"LastVisitTimestamp":0},
    "Complaints":{"ComplaintsTypeA":0,"ComplaintsTypeB":0,"SubstantiatedAllegations":0,"TotalAllegations":0}}}
```

So i tried it like this to get the UUID and other information from the modified json file:

```
UUID = data["added"]["UUID"]
```

but i'm getting this error:

```
KeyError: 'added'
```

Comment: `data['added']['125hk24h5kjh43k5']['UUID']`

Comment: What happens when you tried the old code: `UUID = data.get('UUID', None)`?

Comment: @quamrana With that old code i get: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: There must be something else wrong because the snippets of `json` that you show don't have any lists in them. You should try: `print(data)` to see what your method is actually receiving.

Comment: I'm relatively new to json so i assumed the part that is called "added" is like the listname. When i use the version that i have on my prod server i get this error (I got rid of this part of the code for testing purposes since this error sounds more like part of a bigger issue): 
```
  File "C:\management\commands\import.py", line 23, in import_facility_from_file
    PrimaryAddress = data["AddressInfo"]["PrimaryAddress"]
KeyError: 'AddressInfo'
```

Comment: Adding print(data) as you suggested prints out the data the way it is written inside the old json file without the "list names" "added", "modified", "deleted" @quamrana

Comment: It sounds like the `json` file is being pre-processed for you before your `import_facility_from_file()` method gets to see it. btw your `data` parameter seems to be a `dict`, so its nothing to do with `json` except that `data` follows its format.

Comment: `from hades import smoking_hot_schema` ? (Joke)

Comment: I'm running my python file inside Django and all i have above the code i posted is "import json"

Comment: @quamrana I updated the code above. I forgot the json encoding bits i have at the end of my file 
```
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """
        Call the function to import data from json url
        """
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.get(
            url=IMPORT_URL,
            headers=headers,
        )

        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()

        for key, data_object in data.items():
            self.import_facility_from_file(data_object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `json` format has changed underneath you and you need to adapt.

How about processing all the items in both the `"added"` and `"modified"` sections?

```py
for key, data_object in data.items():
    if key in ["added", "modified"]:
        for key, data in data_object.items():
            self.import_facility_from_file(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

*`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`* because you've list data type in between your dictionary so you can add check for type like this

```
for key, data_object in data.items():
  if type(data_object) == dict:
    for data in data_object.values():
      self.import_facility_from_file(data)
```